# Can we have multiple offers in one iOS Subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription

My need is to achieve iOS monthly subscription that offers 14days free trial -> After trial 3 months 50% off -> After three months regular price every month.
Is this possible?

Below is what i tried but was unable to figure out the above need
introductory offer(works only for new users) can be used for 14days free trial
However i cant use it along with promotional offer as it works only for exising users

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this, but it requires a little work from the user in that they need to use an offer code:

1. Your "14 days free trial" is an Introductory Offer, that's available once for every person who subscribes to your SKU.
2. The next part, you'd need to do via Offer Codes, and the user would have to complete the process to accept the offer code either prior to starting the intro offer (so it could be the first thing they sign up for), or at least during the intro offer period. For this, you'd create an offer code for 3 months at half price, and make it available for at least "new & existing" subscribers - you could also add "expired" subscribers in there too if you wanted it to be possible to use this code as a "winback" offer.

Users will see something like this example from an app I work on, where the first line is the intro offer, the second line is the offer code, and the third line is the standard price:
[image: Image of screen displayed by Apple during purchase of a subscription with Introductory Offer, and Offer Code]